# What features did Ubuntu have on by default that made it like Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, defaults

In the last line of this [explain xkcd](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/424:_Security_Holes) it says, "This may be a reference to Ubuntu being developed with non-advanced users in mind, with many fail-safes and additional features being turned on by default, which had more in common with Windows than any other Linux-based operating system at the time."

What were features in Ubuntu that were turned on by default as opposed to other distros? Is Ubuntu the same in this regard now as it was in 2008? And finally, how much interest should I devote to them as someone who is only beginning with linux?

Comment: I may be wrong, but judging from [release notes for 8.10    version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntrepidReleaseNotes) Ubuntu's `apt` package manager,  in accordance with Debian policy, would install packages marked as "Recommended", i.e. those which aren't essential to whether package you install runs or not. So it would install more than you need. But I've no actual sources to see if this is really what xkcd is referencing

Comment: That's fine. I'm just very new, but I have been enjoying the shell.

Comment: Welcome ! Hope you like Ubuntu and  Linux in general so far. The fact that you're enjoying shell helps - most troubleshootings require that, plus it's just a nicer way to get things done. I generally have bunch of terminals open and a browser.  There are some gotchas, but you'll pick them up over time.

Comment: Bear in mind that [such contributions to wikis](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?diff=139244&oldid=122784) are not necessarily correct or explainable by anyone other than their authors.